# What to do when VSCode is not giving me an error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to C# (did some stuff in python earlier) and i cant get this code to work. Im making a mobile game and this script should run a timer, check if the timer is equal to "SaleTime" and if it is add money to the users balance and reset the timer to 0.
As VSCode is not giving me any errors i dont know what the problem is and after looking around i cant find a solution to it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Sales : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Timer = 0.0f;
    public float SaleTime = 5.0f;
    public float ProductValue = 5.0f;
    public float Money = 1000.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(time());
    }

    public void GameTime()
    {
        Timer += 1;
    }
    IEnumerator time()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            GameTime();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
    public void SaleFunction()
    {
        if (Timer == SaleTime)
        {
            Timer = 0.0f;
            Money = Money + ProductValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling SaleFunction(),  so the program never checks the condition.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Sales : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Timer = 0.0f;
    public float SaleTime = 5.0f;
    public float ProductValue = 5.0f;
    public float Money = 1000.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(time());
    }

    public void GameTime()
    {
        Timer += 1;
    }
    IEnumerator time()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            GameTime();
            SaleFunction(); // Added line.
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
    public void SaleFunction()
    {
        if (Timer == SaleTime)
        {
            Timer = 0.0f;
            Money = Money + ProductValue;
        }
    }
}
```